# asp.net core, angular2: should wwwroot folder contains scss and typescript files?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I can't understand where to place my ts and scss files? wwwroot folder is for static files, but ts and scss files are compiled. Should I hold similar folder structure in wwwroot and outside it and then copy css and js files to wwwroot?

For example:
[image]

Wouldn't it be too complicated? It seems it's very hard to maintain and navigate.

[image]

Comment: use angular-cli do a prod build, copy the contents of dist folder in wwwroot and you are good to go.

Comment: If you are using your own build system, then there should be an dist/output folder in that system. you need to copy that. Angular does not need ts and scss files

Comment: Yes, I agree. It's just in every tutorial I've seen before. Install angular2 using Bower and then copy the library to lib folder. I guess I should discovery this question deeper. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I hold similar folder structure in wwwroot and outside it and then copy css and js files to wwwroot? [sic]

Yes. That is a good idea.

Once you have a handle on that, do more complicated tasks like bundling and minification.

Your question has many, many possible answers. That said, your screenshots show a `gulpfile.js` and you can use [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) to do the following:

1. build your TypeScript and put the `*.js` output into `wwwroot`.
2. build your SCSS and put the `*.css` output into `wwwroot`.

Here are some resources to get you started.

- [A gulp plugin for very fast TypeScript compilation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-tsb)
- [Gulp plugin for sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass)

Here is an example `gulpfile.js` for you to modify based on your specific needs.

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var tsb = require('gulp-tsb');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

// create and keep compiler 
var compilation = tsb.create({
    target: 'es5'
});

gulp.task('tsc', function() {
    return gulp.src('./scripts/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(compilation()) // <- new compilation 
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/appScripts'));
});

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/css'));
});
```

You will need to have some understanding of `npm` and `gulp`. Basically, from the command line you will run the following gulp tasks.

```
gulp tsc     // to build typescript
gulp sass    // to build sass
```

They will find your `*.ts` and `*.scss` files, build them, and save them into the specified destinations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to use both gulp and npm. It's ok, I don't have questions about it. It's just about identical folder structures. Please, see update of the question.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/sirajc/angular2-starter - It uses gulp, ts and sass - This will help you get started with what you want to achieve

Comment: @shkiper The question about how to setup your folder structure is really subjective. siraj provides a good suggestion: look at canonical samples, then emulate one that you like.